# Дурак - третий сын?

Tags: этимология

Слово "дурак" тут уже, по-моему, не раз обсуждалось. Но я услышала новую версию значения этого слова. Мол, дураком называли изначально третьего сына в семье. Именно поэтому в сказках Иван Дурак - всегда третий по старшинству. Но, с другой стороны, насколько я знаю, третьего сына называли третьяком - отсюда и современная фамилия.
Имеет ли эта версия под собой реальную почву?

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю...
Ну нету у "дурака" такого значения как "третий" - да еще сын. Да и неоткуда ему взяться... 
И потом, если третий - дурак по определению, что, собственно, может сообщить слушателю фраза "третий вовсе был дурак"?

Нет, я полагаю, что автор этой идеи или просто пропиарил себя, или неудачно выразился, имея в виду всего лишь фольклорную составляющую: типа "по сказкам так положено третьему дураком быть", но совсем не обязательно в жизни.

Answer (score 0):

Современная сказка: И жили у отца три сына... А квартиры свои сдавали.

Как видим, и Третий - совсем не дурак.